# Macro to run SQL queries in Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have a bunch of SQL queries that I have created in Excel by using cell references as parameters.  All the queries are stored as strings in one column.  Rather than use the Microsoft Query to create a connection for each SQL query, is there a way that I can have a macro run down the column and execute each one of the queries from each cell and output the result in the cell directly to the right of it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using ADODB? I assumed SQL is placed in A1 and below:

```
Const MY_CONNECTION_STRING = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=X;Database=Y;Trusted_Connection=Yes"
Sub RunSQL()
Dim cnn, c, rs
Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cnn.Open MY_CONNECTION_STRING
For Each c In Range("A1:A" & UsedRange.Rows.Count)
    Set rs = cnn.Execute(c.Value)
    c.Next.Value = rs.collect(0)
    rs.Close
Next c
cnn.Close
End Sub
```